# Closing Transmission Error. Timeout waiting for the data from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using local host to send bulk mails through SES. This question is answered by many but none of the solutions is helping me. The problem is I could send 100/ 150 mails at a time after that the above error is showing up. I tried to dispose of the client as suggested by some, but not working. I am using C# code to do this. Any answers/ suggestions is much appreciated. The below is the code I am using to send bulk mail using for loop. You might be thinking it might be a throttling issue, it is not because we have 70 emails/second and 500000 emails per day.

```
Parallel.For(0, mail.Count, i =>
{
    // Replace with your "From" address. This address must be verified.
    String TO = mail; // Replace with a "To" address. If your account is still in the
    // sandbox, this address must be verified.

    // Create an SMTP client with the specified host name and port.
    using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
    {
        // Create a network credential with your SMTP user name and password.
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

        //Use SSL when accessing Amazon SES. The SMTP session will begin on an unencrypted connection, and then 
        //the client will issue a STARTTLS command to upgrade to an encrypted connection using SSL.
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message1 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(FROM, TO, SUBJECT, BODY);

        message1.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Send(message1);
        client.Dispose();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your local machine has finite resources (CPU, Internet bandwidth, and memory, to name a few).  If you are sending 100+ messages *concurrently*, you may not have enough of one or more resources available to reliably *service* all of those separate TCP connections and SMTP sessions in a sufficiently timely manner to prevent some of them from timing out.  Have you considered that?  If you benchmarked each smtp session from start to finish, I expect you would pass a certain threshold, after which things start slowing down "unexpectedly."

Comment: My local machine has 4 GB RAM and 16Mbps internet speed. Is this configuration not sufficient to run the application correctly?

Comment: It isn't possible to answer that, based on raw numbers.  Please consider benchmarking your code to gain a better understanding of the nature of your issue.

Comment: how to bench mark my code ?

Comment: Log and/or capture the current time with a precision of milliseconds or greater, at selected steps in your code, and subtract the difference, to determine how long each request takes, from start to finish.  At a certain number of concurrent requests, you should expect to see performance degrade, with the time for each request increasing more than you may expect.  Also, monitor your system's memory usage and CPU usage, from outside your code, while the code is running. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)

Comment: Thank you Michael for answering..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason why it is working now, but it's working. I changed the logic of the above code, it started working. Instead of fetching the SMTP connection each time, for sending each mail previously, this time I fetched the smtp connection only once and used it to send all the bulk mails at once and it started working.But the problem is the sending time, it is taking too much to send all the mails.Anyways I will find the solution for this also.

```
using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
{
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    for(i=0;i<mail.Count;i++)
    {
        String TO = mail[i];
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message1 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(FROM, TO, SUBJECT, BODY);

        message1.IsBodyHtml = true;

        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Send(message1);
    }

    client.Dispose();
}

Label1.Text = mail.Count.ToString() + " mails sent !!";
```